# Checking occurrence of certain character in each row in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a simple table prepared in Excel

```
+---------------+
|     name      |
+---------------+
| ST-PL-100-1   |
| ST-PL-700     |
| ST-PL-100-14  |
| ST-PL-100-6   |
| ST-PL-100     |
| ST-PL-300     |
| ST-PL-100-632 |
+---------------+
```

I want to display the rows that have only 2 dashes.

My expected results:

```
ST-PL-700
ST-PL-100
ST-PL-300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom column to determine the number of dashes.  Then filter on `2`

Custom column formula:

```
Text.Length([name])-Text.Length(Text.Replace([name],"-",""))
```

After you do the filtering, you can delete the "dashCount" custom column so it doesn't show up when you load the query back to the worksheet.

As an aside, this can also be done in native Excel with the Advanced Filter, using a formula criteria

`=LEN(firstDataCell)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(firstDataCell,"-",""))=2`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a dummy column in the Power Query Editor.

Mark the column "Name". Then click "Add Column" -> Custom Column.

[image]

Enter the formula `=Text.Start([name],9)`

Where `[name]` is the name of the column you want to change and `9` is how many characters from left that should be in the new column. You could also set a new name for your column, I just used "Column".

[image]

This is the result, your old column to the left and the new one to the right.

[image]

If you only want to keep unique values you could use "remove duplicates"

[image]